# Hide 'configure block' for Omega theme?

Tags: 7, theming

How can I hide the 'configure block' mouseover from appearing? Im using the Omega theme.

Its breaking parts of my site but I cant stop it from appearing with permissions as certain users need the permission to edit blocks.

Comment: Turn off the Contextual Links module maybe?

Comment: Disabling Contextual Links fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling Contextual Links fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Omega theme version 7.x-3.1, you can go to the templates folder and edit region--content.tpl.php. In line 12 you will find the following:

```
   <?php if ($action_links): ?><ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul><?php endif; ?>
```

You can comment this line out, or delete it.